# Calculating zonal statistics for each polygon in shapefile using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, zonal-statistics, vector-layer, reducers

I have shapefile of counties and want to calculate mean NDVI for each. I know reducing connected components and `ee.reducer.mean` can be helpful in GEE but it wants it as CSV for further analysis in R pl.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to use `.reduceRegions()` to reduce your NDVI image over regions represeted as counties with `ee.Reducer.mean()` reducer.

Then do export with `Export.table.toDrive()` setting `fileFormat` to `'csv'`.

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_regions) official tutorial and [here's](https://code.earthengine.google.com/086b2b09927af114f417ee42bfd0623f) a link to a complete script with exporting.

Note: by default CSV output will contain all attributes from source features + column with an output of a chosen reducer - `"mean"` in this case.